# How to add values to a table with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form and I want that when I click on a button those values are added to a table that I have in another sheet I tried detecting the last row with UsedRange.Row but it gets below the created table. In what way can I solve this?

```
Sub agregar()
    Dim fecha As String
    Dim nombre As String
    Dim dia As String
    Dim cant_1 As Integer
    Dim cant_2 As Integer
    Dim cant_3 As Integer
    Dim ped_1 As String
    Dim ped_2 As String
    Dim ped_3 As String
    Dim pre_1 As Double
    Dim pre_2 As Double
    Dim pre_3 As Double
    Dim procede As String
    Dim ultimafila As Double


    fecha = Cells(4, 3).Value
    nombre = Cells(5, 3).Value
    dia = Cells(4, 5).Value
    cant_1 = Cells(6, 4).Value
    cant_2 = Cells(7, 4).Value
    cant_3 = Cells(8, 4).Value
    ped_1 = Cells(6, 3).Value
    ped_2 = Cells(7, 3).Value
    ped_3 = Cells(8, 3).Value
    pre_1 = Cells(6, 7).Value
    pre_2 = Cells(7, 7).Value
    pre_3 = Cells(8, 7).Value
    procede = Cells(6, 9).Value

    ultimafila = Worksheets("Control semanal").UsedRange.Row - 1 + Worksheets("Control semanal").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 5, 2).Value = dia
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 5, 3) = fecha
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 5, 4) = nombre
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 5, 7) = ped_1
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 6, 7) = ped_2
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 7, 7) = ped_3
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 5, 8) = cant_1
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 6, 8) = cant_2
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 7, 8) = cant_3
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 5, 9) = pre_1
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 6, 9) = pre_2
    Worksheets("Control semanal").Cells(ultimafila + 7, 9) = pre_3

End Sub
```

I want it to be added to the table

Comment: You should use Table References instead of Absolute references in case of table. Follow the [Link](http://realanalysiszone.com/?p=19) to get some useful references.

Comment: To get the last row you should be using `ultimafila = Worksheets("Control semanal").ListObjects("Table Name").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count`:

Answer (score -1):

you can choose to use a combination of keys in the macros, by holding down the control key and pressing a direction key (example below), you will be located in the last element with value in that row or column (insert the value after this)

```
Sub InsertMacro()
    'select a row rank and copy'
    Range("A3:C3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("weekly_control").Select
    'select the first element of the table header'
    'note: table created by the insert table method'
    Range("Tabla1[[#Headers],[NAME]]").Select
    'End(xlDown) = equivalent to Control and direction key (below)'
    'Offset(1, 0) = insert value one row below the last added value'
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'return to previous page and clean range of copied cells'
    Sheets("form").Select
    Range("A3:C3").ClearContents
End Sub
```

The combination code of keys can be opted by creating the macros by means of recordings (this code was optenido by means of a recording and then altered to convenience)